# How do you convert a C# Class Library project to a Silverlight Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight

I accidentally created a C# class library instead of a Silverlight Class Library for quite a few dlls.  Is it possible to modify the project file easily to convert it instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having done this, IMO the easiest thing is to just start afresh. It doesn't take long to copy over a few .cs files and add a few references etc. If you *really* want you could do a comparison on the csproj; the obvious changes are the `<ProjectTypeGuids>`, `<SilverlightApplication>`, `<ValidateXaml>`, `<ProductVersion>` and `<ProjectExtensions>`... and probably many of the references... hmmm - yes, just start afresh; it'll be safer!

If you need to support multiple frameworks, you can cheat (to avoid having to maintain 2+ project files) - I do this in protobuf-net - by including:

```
<Compile Include="..\protobuf-net\**\*.cs" />
```

Which says "compile all the .cs files at any level under the ..\protobuf-net path".